# .htaccess 301 redirect not working - tried Redirect, RewriteMatch, RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am on a LAMP stack on a dedicated server.

In domain root, there is WordPress.

In /finder subfolder, there is another script. This script does not use a .htaccess

We have decided to move a new, OpenSource script which is installed in /squirrel subfolder.

Now we wish to redirect /finder URLs to /squirrel pages, but the slugs are different for the two scripts' pages. So I manually wrote about 300 lines of 301 redirects in an .htaccess and placed the file in the /finder folder. Did not work. For testing, I have reduced the redirects to a single one and even that is not working:
Redirect 301 /finder/art.php http://domain.com/squirrel/

Also tried Redirect, RewriteMatch, RewriteRule, nothing seems to work.

Any suggestion as to how to approach this? I am happy to share more details, but not sure what additional details to share at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `/finder/.htaccess` try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^art\.php$ /squirrel/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

Just remember that since this `.htaccess` is inside `/finder/` folder therefore all the URI patterns for `RewriteRule` must not include `finder/`.

Comment: Thanks mate. Tried. But no cigar.

Comment: What is the **full URL** you entered in browser and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: I entered domain.com/finder/art.php and the .htaccess is in /finder/

Comment: ok first verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: Putting some garbage on top of the .htaccess had a curious effect. Webpage still loaded. But all the images on it are broken. Also, the javascript window opens are now not opening any links...so I guess the JS file is not loading either.

Comment: Clicking on the javascript link shows ReferenceError: open_window is not defined in Firebug console

Comment: With garbage text on top just try loading a non existing page like `domain.com/finder/abcd`

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72088/discussion-between-anubhava-and-oc2ps).

Comment: Also getting 500 for the static files - existing jpg, html etc Somehow the phps seem immune

Comment: [join the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72088/discussion-between-anubhava-and-oc2ps)